# Crystal Report make whole number if decimal is .00

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using SAP Crystal Reports.

I have a field called `discount percent`. I'm making a if statement.

My question is: How do I make it a whole number if decimal places is `.00`

Sample:

```
50.00
43.12
60.40
20.00
13.00
```

Expected Result:

```
50
43.12
60.40
20
13
```

Comment: `ToText(discount percent,0,"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula should return the expected result:

```
If {Table.discountpercent} = Round({Table.discountpercent}, 0) Then
    ToText({Table.discountpercent}, 0)
Else
    ToText({Table.discountpercent}, 2)
```

It checks if `discountpercent` is equal to `discountpercent` rounded to 0 decimals.

If yes, format with 0 decimals, if no, format with 2 decimals.